# Android bluetooth application process killed

Tags: android, bluetooth, connection

I'm very new with programming for android. I have two classes : main and btmanager. When i try to test my app on phone, all I get is a information that procees was killed. What am I doing wrong ?

Code implementation :

Main class :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

BluetoothAdapter bluetooth = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

Btmanager manager;


@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (bluetooth == null)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is not enabled on this device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        System.exit(0);
    }


}

@Override
public void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();

    if (!bluetooth.isEnabled()) {
        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 2);
    }

    manager.run();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}




public void closeApp (View view)
{
    System.exit(0);
}
}
```

Btmanager class :

```
public class Btmanager extends Thread {

private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
public static final UUID myUUID = UUID.fromString("0x1101");
BluetoothAdapter bluetooth = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

public Btmanager(BluetoothDevice device) {
    // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmSocket,
    // because mmSocket is final
    BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
    mmDevice = device;

    // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice
    try {
        // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the server code
        tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(myUUID);
    } catch (IOException e) { }
    mmSocket = tmp;
}

public void run() {
    // Cancel discovery because it will slow down the connection
    bluetooth.cancelDiscovery();

    try {
        // Connect the device through the socket. This will block
        // until it succeeds or throws an exception
        mmSocket.connect();
    } catch (IOException connectException) {
        // Unable to connect; close the socket and get out
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException closeException) { }
        return;
    }

}

/** Will cancel an in-progress connection, and close the socket */
public void cancel() {
    try {
        mmSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) { }
}
```

Comment: have you given Bluetooth Permission in AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: Yes. Copied form my app manifest file : <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />

Comment: ok run your application in device, while connecting with USB and upload the error log,

Answer (score 2):

2 problems I see in your code:

1. You don't instantiate the `Btmanager` object, it is still `null` when you call `run`. (Will cause a `NullPointerException` - your app will crash).
2. You call the `run` method instead of the `start` method of the `Btmanager`. If you want the code in the `run` method to run in a new thread, you have to call `start`. Calling `run` will cause it to run in the **same** thread. This blocks your UI thread which may cause your app to crash, if it blocks for too long.

Comment: Ok, now I create Btmanager object by constructor but albo have one question about threads. I have to call method 'start' instead of 'run' ?

Answer (score 0):

For test purporses, I don't use BTmanager class - in onStart() method I add new thread with connection implentation, but still without any results - app crash.

```
public void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();

    if (!bluetooth.isEnabled()) {
        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 2);
    }


    new Thread(new Runnable() 
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            try {
                //Create a Socket connection: need the server's UUID number of registered
                socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(myUUID);

                socket.connect();
                Log.d("EF-BTBee", "Connectted");
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Log.e("EF-BTBee", "Error : ", e);
            }
        }
    }).start();


}
```

Comment: Can it be wrong UUID ? I use BTM222 module. In Windows I find UUID `0x1101` but google says `00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB` ?